# WPF- how to create a kind of a screensaver (with timer)

Tags: c#, wpf, timer

I do not know how to solve this problem:

I want in my WPF Application something like a screensaver which pops up (let's say after 20 seconds) if you do not interact with the program. I tried researching, but I did not find anything and I do not know how to start. Does anyone have any tips for me?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22619326/wpf-create-a-screen-saver-feature-when-application-is-inactive

Comment: Possible duplicate of [WPF: Create a screen-saver feature when application is inactive?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22619326/wpf-create-a-screen-saver-feature-when-application-is-inactive)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can for example start `DispacherTimer` and reset it if person move mouse or click something. In event check is time's up start new window/popup/dialog modal with screensaver, if person move mouse or click in screensaver close it and back to previous window.

Something about `DispacherTimer` you can find here:
[WPF Timer Like C# Timer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5410430/wpf-timer-like-c-sharp-timer)
or here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/system.windows.threading.dispatchertimer%28v=vs.90%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like [this](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/31376/Making-a-C-screensaver) then all you have to do is just set a timmer in the app.cs that resets.

```
    private DispatcherTimer _timer;
    protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
    {
        _timer = new DispatcherTimer();
        _timer.Tick += Timer_Tick;
        _timer.Interval = new TimeSpan(0,0,0,20,0);
        _timer.Start();

        EventManager.RegisterClassHandler(typeof(Window),Window.MouseMoveEvent, new RoutedEventHandler(Reset_Timer));
        EventManager.RegisterClassHandler(typeof(Window), Window.MouseDownEvent, new RoutedEventHandler(Reset_Timer));
        EventManager.RegisterClassHandler(typeof(Window), Window.KeyDownEvent, new RoutedEventHandler(Reset_Timer));
    }

    private void Timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Ticked");
    }

    private void Reset_Timer(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        _timer.Interval = new TimeSpan(0,0,0,20,0);
    }
```

This will reset the timer every time you move your mouse click your mouse or push any key in the window.